# Do "шильдик" and "shield" have a common root?

Tags: этимология

These words are similar in pronunciation and meaning. Do they have a common root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA), `шильдик` originated from German "Schild" that's likely to have common descent with English "Shield".

Comment: Я смотрел на [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA), там не указано происхождение, на wikipedia посмотреть не догадался, спасибо!

Comment: я даже не знал, что это самостоятельное слово, и использую «шильдик» исключительно в значении «картинки, что предлагает https://shields.io ». Т.о., в моём случае это не общее происхождение с shield, а транслитеракция shield

Answer (score 0):

Surely both are from German "Schild".

Comment: They are cognate to German "Schild", not "from" it.

Comment: @Quassnoi At least "шильдик" cannot be cognate.

Comment: the Russian word is derived from the German, of course. My (badly worded) point was that the English one was not.

Comment: may we suppose, both English and German words are from some shared Old-English-Old-Germanic ancestor? :-D

Comment: @Arioch Proto-Germanic language (прагерманский язык).